# Ng --version shows an error on a devlopment package

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

When I clone a repo, I get an error on a development package.
Any advice on how to solve this will be very helpfull.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angular cli is showing version which is equal to 12.1.2. It's fine.

But typescript version is showing error.
Have you correctly installed typescript.
Please check using this command `tsc -v` and comment the result.

Comment: Helo Kartik, thank you for your response. Yes I solved the typescript error installing typescript. After that I tried to solve the other error installing @angular-devkit/build-angular with the command: 'npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular'. This tried to create the node-modules folder, but my console launched a lot of errors.

Comment: What is your node version?